# How to get a file name currently being read into SAS?

Tags: sas

`%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME)` and `%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)` are about the SAS program submitted but what about the data file itself? I use `INFILE` statement in DATA step and Filename= and others characteristics are written into SAS LOG, but how to print the file name being read like a TITLE ?

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  Are you reading a file with a wildcard or otherwise not directly specifying the file you're reading?  How is this TITLE being output - are you printing the dataset to the screen after reading it or something else?

Comment: Joe, you're right. I want to see it over the data set after running the proc print procedure.

Comment: Are you hard-coding the filename in, ie, `data mydata; infile "c:\myfile.dat"; input ...; run;`?  Or is this a wildcarded or otherwise not directly specified file/set of files?

Comment: Maybe best would be if you could write out the entire code in an example that you'd like to write, substituting an imaginary macro variable for the filename that you'd like to have access to, &SYSLASTFILENAME or whatever (which does not exist of course).

Comment: Yes, I use data-infile-input-run. I'm not an experienced sas user. My idea is to run a code with one data set and later - with dozens. So when I print dataset I want to see it above the dataset say in a pdf file or just in the SAS Results Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INFILE` statement option `FILENAME=variable`

From help

> **FILENAME=variable**
>
> specifies a variable that SAS sets to the physical name of the
> currently opened input file. In a series of concatenated files, the
> variable is updated only after SAS encounters the next file. As with
> automatic variables, the FILENAME=variable is not written to the data
> set.

In a related scenario, you can use option `FILEVAR=variable` to dynamically specify which file the INPUT statement is to read from.